# Why is `==` not a satisfactory condition for this problem given that our template minimizes the position k such that the condition is true?

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements, binary-search

This question is in response to the popular leetcode binary search template posted a few years ago, and [**you might understand my question more completely if you read the thread where I originally asked the question.**](https://leetcode.com/discuss/general-discussion/786126/Python-Powerful-Ultimate-Binary-Search-Template.-Solved-many-problems/1796834)  But I will do my best to explain here so you don't have to leave this tab.

[**LeetCode question:**](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-first-and-last-position-of-element-in-sorted-array/) Given an array of integers nums sorted in non-decreasing order, find the starting and ending position of a given target value.
If target is not found in the array, return [-1, -1].

**Proposed solution:**

```
def searchRange(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    def find_first(target):
        left, right = 0, len(nums) - 1
        while left < right:
            mid = left + (right - left) // 2
            if nums[mid] >= target:
                right = mid
            else:
                left = mid + 1
        return left

    nums.append(float('inf'))
    if not nums:
        return [-1, -1]
    first_position = find_first(target)
    if nums[first_position] != target: 
        return [-1, -1]
    last_position = find_first(target + 1) - 1
    return [first_position, last_position]
```

**Reasoning behind why we use the condition `nums[mid] >= target`:** For this problem, the first position is the minimal k satisfying nums[k] >= target, and the last position is the minimal k satisfying nums[k] > target minus 1.

**Context for my question:** This was initally a post sharing a binary search template that purports to "find the minimum position k such that our condition is satisfied. Becasue of this premise, I asked the question below:

**My actual question:**

I am a little confused as to why "the first position is the minimal k satisfying `nums[k] >= target`". I completely understand "why" `>=` works in the context of this binary search template, however, the idiom, in this case, does not make sense to me. We are in fact not looking to satisfy the condition of `nums[k] >` anything. We are only looking for when `nums[k]` equals the target. The template purports to find the minimal k for the condition you use. So if the condition I am actually interested in is `==`, then shouldn't the template which has the condition we desire, seek out the minimal k for it? Why do I need to add `>` to make it work?

While writing this, I had a bit of intuition come to me, so maybe this answers my own question: since there is a possibility that the target does not exist in the list but our question includes the statement "first position" we still need to have `>` in order to qualify our condition for what is asked, when the target is missing. If the target was not in the list, we still want our condition to satisfy where the number would "first occur", not just "where it occurs". (despite the fact that we return `-1` if the target is missing, anyway)

I hope the nature of my question is clear here. Again, I have looked at the math behind why `>=` target works and  `==` does not work (if target is in right hand space of list, it won't work). I'm merely trying to reconcile why `==` does not work here given the idiom/rule that the template finds the minimum k of any condition we ask. It doesn't feel like `==` is the wrong condition.

It feels like the minimum position, `k`, such that `nums[k] == target` and `nums[k] >= target` should have the same meaning, except for when the target is missing, and in this case we return `-1` anyway

I tried something very similar to the proposed solution, excecpt the condition I used was nums[k] == target as oppsoed to nums[k] >= target. I was expecting the template to find the minimal k such that the value at position k was equal to the target. This is basically that the template purports to do. Find the minimal k such that your condition is met. I'm not sure why I need to add `>` to ensure we find the first position since the rest of the code should be handling the "first position" part of the question.

Comment: I assume `nums` are sorted? If so, that means you have guarantees that all numbers before/after any given position are less/greater than any other. If they aren't sequential values, then you shouldn't use equal operator, as you want to stop the search on the next greater (or equal) value

Comment: If the only condition you check is equality, and the element you check happens to not be equal, then how would you know which way to move in order to find the desired element?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Although nums are sorted, they are likely to have duplicates. I.e [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]. So I would not say that there is a guarantee that all numbers before/after any given position are less/greater than any other.

Comment: @jasonharper My thinking here is that the template finds the minimum k such that the condition is true. Basically, given my condition, it should just find the left most value. This actually appears to be the case when the target lies on the left hand side of the list but not the right. 

I agree though, >= lets you know which direction to go. However, I'm not sure it supports the idea that this template finds the minimum k such that condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

Lets break this down a bit by making some visualization. You could print a table showing how the search is performing, by showing where left and right are on each iteration in relation to the values.

```
def print_search(nums, left, right):
    print(''.join(f" {i:<2} |" for i in range(len(nums))))
    print(''.join("----|" for _ in range(len(nums))))
    print(''.join(f" {n:<2} |" for n in nums))
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        x = "L" if i == left else "R" if i == right else ""
        print(f" {x:<2} |", end="")
    print()
    print()
```

Adding this into the search:

```
def find_first(nums, target):
    left, right = 0, len(nums) - 1
    while left < right:
        print_search(nums, left, right)
        mid = left + (right - left) // 2
        if nums[mid] >= target:
            right = mid
        else:
            left = mid + 1
    print_search(nums, left, right)
    return left
```

Running this code, we can see how the search is executed.

```
>>> find_first([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8], 2)
 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
 1  | 1  | 1  | 2  | 2  | 3  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 7  | 7  | 8  |
 L  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | R  |

 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
 1  | 1  | 1  | 2  | 2  | 3  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 7  | 7  | 8  |
 L  |    |    |    |    |    | R  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |

 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
 1  | 1  | 1  | 2  | 2  | 3  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 7  | 7  | 8  |
 L  |    |    | R  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |

 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
 1  | 1  | 1  | 2  | 2  | 3  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 7  | 7  | 8  |
    |    | L  | R  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |

 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
 1  | 1  | 1  | 2  | 2  | 3  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 7  | 7  | 8  |
    |    |    | L  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
3
```

Now what happens when you change `nums[k] >= target` to `nums[k] == target`?

```
>>> find_first([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8], 2)
 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
 1  | 1  | 1  | 2  | 2  | 3  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 7  | 7  | 8  |
 L  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | R  |

 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
 1  | 1  | 1  | 2  | 2  | 3  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 7  | 7  | 8  |
    |    |    |    |    |    |    | L  |    |    |    |    |    | R  |

 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
 1  | 1  | 1  | 2  | 2  | 3  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 7  | 7  | 8  |
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | L  |    | R  |

 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
 1  | 1  | 1  | 2  | 2  | 3  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 7  | 7  | 8  |
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | L  |
13
```

We can see that this is clearly wrong. Because we are checking for `nums[k] == target` we decided to move the left anchor instead of the right. This moves left past the search area we actually wanted, and leaves us with the wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

[I asked this question on reddit and found a satisfactory answer.](https://www.reddit.com/r/leetcode/comments/10zs1fs/comment/j857p1n/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

> You should look at Binary Search as an array of booleans so you don't
> get confused. In fact, in order for you to use BS, the function must
> be monotonic. For example:
>
> A = [1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6], target = 4, using A[mid] >= target condition
> gives [F, F, T, T, T, T]. As the template you are using is finding the
> first True occurence, if the condition is true you can discard right
> half by setting r = m. (We don't use r = m -1 because m could still be
> the answer). If the condition is False, we can confidently move l =
> m+1 since whatever on the left are Falses and we are only interested
> in the first True.
>
> Now if you use A[mid] == target condition, it gives [F, F, T, T, F,
> F]. How do you know where to move your l/r pointers? If you want to
> use A[mid] == target condition, you must save intermediate result in
> another variable and separate the condition from the binary search
> conditions. Check Enrichto's template.